# How are range and len being used in for loops

Tags: python

I just want to know what is going on in this program

```
  sum = 0 #setting sum to 0
  for i in range(len(m)): 
    for j in range(len(m[i])):
      if i <= j:
        sum = sum + m[i][j]
  return sum

print((sum_above_diagonal([[6, 2, 0, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 5, 8], [0, 6, 3, 2, 3]])))
```

I understand the first part, but I am confused on the 'for i in range (len())' stuff.

Comment: What's confusing? Do you know what `len` does? `range`? The `for` loop?

Comment: In this case, the name of the function is accurately describing what the function does. Do you understand how the nested list is representing a matrix?

Comment: Right your program execution down, on paper. Step by step...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have this array:

```py
arr = [[0,1,2],[9,8,7]]
```

The first *for* will run 2 times because `len(arr)=2` and the second for will run 3 times because `len(arr[0])=3`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode might help:

```
Start with counting the sum from zero
For each number i between zero and the number of rows in the matrix, do this:
    For each number j between zero and the number of columns in row i, do this:
        If i is equal to, or larger than, j, do this:
            Add the value of this cell (i, j) to the sum, and save the new sum 

And then we return the sum when we are done
```

So, this will, as the function name suggests, sum the number above and on the diagonal of the matrix you give to it. The matrix is a list of lists.

Edit:
len(thing) gives you the length of the thing
range(N) generates integers between 0 and N-1
So these combined gives you integers between 0 and the length of something minus one.

Answer (score 0):

That `range(len(X))` combo is indeed a bit unusual, you can also use Python's builtin [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) and write something like so:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(X):
    ...
```